# The value of $f_x((0,0))+f_y((0,0))+f_{xy}((0,0)) $ is?

Tags: linear-transformations, partial-derivative, multivariate-polynomial

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \Rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by
$$f((x,y)) = x^2 +2y^2 -3xy, \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
The value of $f_x((0,0))+f_y((0,0))+f_{xy}((0,0))$ is:

- $0$
- Undefined
- $-3$
- 3

I'm puzzled since in my opinion the value should be $0$, while the correct answer has been reported to be $-3$.
To get $f_x$ you take the partial derivative for $x$ of $f_{xy}$ and the same for $y$.
$$f(x) = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \text{ and } f(y) = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$$
So, if I haven't made my calculations wrong (they are fairly simple):
$$ f(x) = 2x -3y \text{ and } f(y) = 4y -3x $$
$$ \Rightarrow f_x((0,0)) = 2\cdot0 -3\cdot0 = 0 \text{ and } f_y((0,0))= 4 \cdot 0 - 3 \cdot 0 = 0 \text{ and } f_{xy}((0,0)) = 0^2+2 \cdot0^2 -3 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 = 0$$
Each function is zero at $(0,0)$, or not? Am I missing something? The linear transformation shouldn't change anything since, by definition, the origin doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $-3$.

Let $f:\begin{cases} \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}&\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\\(x,y)&\longmapsto x^{2}+2y^{2}-3xy \end{cases}$ then clearly $f\in \mathcal{C}^{+\infty}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$ and then we have

- $f_{x}(x,y)=2x-3y$ then $f_{x}(0,0)=2\cdot 0-3\cdot 0=0$ so $f_{x}(0,0)=0$.
- $f_{y}(x,y)=4y-3x$ then $f_{y}(0,0)=4\cdot 0-3\cdot 0=0$ so $f_{y}(0,0)=0$.
- $f_{xy}(x,y)=(f_{x})_{y}(x,y)=(2x-3y)_{y}=-3$ so $f_{xy}(0,0)=-3$.

Therefore,
$$f_{x}(0,0)+f_{y}(0,0)+f_{xy}(0,0)=0+0-3=-3.$$

Comment: Thank you very much @user1027216 ! Now I think I understand my mistake. Let me see if I understood correctly. $ f_{xy}((0,0)) $ must be evaluated as $(f_x)_y(x,y) = \frac {\partial f_x} {\partial y} = -3$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You can see it as $f_{xy}(x,y)=(f_{x})_{y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{\partial f_{x}}{\partial y}(x,y)=-3$ since $f(x,y)=x^{2}+2y^{2}-3xy$ then $f_{x}(x,y)=2x-3y$ then $(f_{x})_{y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f_{x}}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial (2x-3y)}{\partial y}(x,y)=-3$ as you said.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f_{xy}=-3$ since $f_x=2x-3y$ and then evaluating at $(0,0)$ gives $-3$.

Comment: Well, if $f_{xy}(x,y)=2x+4y-3$ then $f_{xy}(0,0)=-3$ all right. However, at $(0,1)$ we get in your function $f_{xy}(0,1)=2\cdot 0+4\cdot 1-3=1$. But since $f(x,y)=x^{2}+2y^{2}-3xy$ we get for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, $f_{xy}(x,y)=-3$ contradiction with your function give $1$.

Comment: @user1027216 where did you get the idea that $(0,1)$ was relevant to the problem?

Comment: It is relevant, because your function $f_{x,y}(x,y)=2x+4y-3$ shows that it is constant for some $(x,y)$ values on its domain, but the function $(x,y)\mapsto f_{xy}$ is constant for all $(x,y)$ in its domain and its value is fixed $-3$.

Comment: @user1027216 The partial derivatives of a polynomial function are not hard to calculate. Have you taken a first course in calculus?

Comment: My answer is written right here in the other answer. However notice that $f(x,y)=x^{2}+2y^{2}-3xy$ then $f_{x}(x,y)=2x-3y$ then $f_{xy}(x,y)=(f_{x})_{y}(x,y)=-3$. Your notation $f_{xy}=2x+4y-3$ is ambiguous and does not make sense in the analysis. However I will no longer continue to respond, anyway. Mathematics must be rigorous all the time.

Comment: @user1027216 ah, you are overexplaining it. $f_x =2x-3y$ is sufficient to reveal the error. Thanks though!